# print(~(123 >> 1)) outputs -62 on Dart Mobile but outputs 4294967234 on Dart Web

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I narrowed down my question from [Same dart code outputs different result on Web and Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655147/same-dart-code-outputs-different-result-on-web-and-mobile) to this single line of code

```
print(~(123 >> 1));
```

Why does this print `-62` on Dart mobile and `4294967234` on Dart web

What is the workaround or correct solution to make the same code "multiplatform"

**Edit**

```
~ // what is this operator ? this is the route cause I guess
```

Comment: I was curious and tried in Firefox, it's `-62` there.

Comment: Are you able to see the compiled JS code that dart creates?

Comment: I tried this on dart pad on Chrome

Comment: The `~` operator is the bitwise NOT operator. The difference is likely between engines that treat the argument as unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Solved . Replaced the ~ with

```
 // This is equivalent to the bitwise NOT operator ~ 
  // However, this outputs a wrong a value on web,
  // so we do it manually
  static int bitwiseNot(int x) {
    return -x - 1;
  }
```